# force a specific constructor used solely in certain code, nowhere else

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11

Sometimes, we need to provide a specific constructor solely for test usage. How can we force such constructor is solely used in test code, nowhere else.
I just wonder if this is achievable in c++11/14. e.g.,

```
class A {
public: 
  A() = default; // used only in test code
}
class A_Test : public ::testing::Test {
 private:
  A a; // it is ok.
};
class A_Production {
 private:
  A a;  // compiler error
}
```

I could imagine to use `friend` decorator and put the specific constructor in `protected` to limit the access. but there are other existing friends in legacy code too. Is it possible to make a custom specifier like protected in c++1x?

any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but a workaround would be to create one (or more) wrapper class(es) somehow depending on your requirements or redesign the structure of the project so that you really don't have that problem, and I'm wondering if you have this problem it's because you have a bad design.

Comment: well, i think this is a pretty reasonable requirement.

Comment: If your test code is executing a different code path than your production code then it _probably_ isn't very good test code.

Comment: well, it is not unusual for testing, e.g., you have to provide a different constructor for mocking purpose. The coding path is the same, as it tests behaviour not constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Passkey Idiom](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/10/passkey-idiom-more-useful-empty-classes-arne-mertz):

Instead of a direct friendship, you limit the access to `A` from `A_Test` through the indirection provided by `ConstructorKey`, which `A` uses in its interface where it wants the friends of `ConstructorKey` to access.

```
class A {
  class ConstructorKey {
    friend class A_Test;
  private:
    ConstructorKey() {};
    ConstructorKey(ConstructorKey const&) = default;
  };
public: 
  // Whoever can provide a key has access:
  explicit A(ConstructorKey); // Used only in test code
};

class A_Test : public ::testing::Test {
 private:
  A a {ConstructorKey{}}; // OK
};

class A_Production {
 private:
  A a {ConstructorKey{}}; // Compiler error
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several ways to do that.

1. Make the constructor `protected`, with only the test subclass using it.
2. Add a forward declaration to some dummy class, `class TestClassThatShouldNotBeUsedInProductionCode;`, then declare a constructor that takes a reference to this class as a parameter:

   ```
   A::A( /* other constructor arguments */,
         const TestClassThatShouldNotBeUsedInProductionCode &)
   ```

This constructor can simply ignore this parameter altogether. Your test module can define this dummy, empty class: `class TestClassThatShouldNotBeUsedInProductionCode {};`, and be able to construct your `A` class using it. Only your test module would be able to use this constructor, then, and its name makes it pretty clear what the purpose of this is. There isn't really any way to define certain translation units as "real" code versus "test" code, in C++, you just want to implement a clear policy that would be hard to violate accidentally.

Some variations are possible, such as using an inner class instead of forward-declaring a standalone class. The inner class could only be instantiated only by the test code.

Comment: These are workarounds, not sure if this problem should even arise.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, in the cpp file that does the testing of A:

```
#define private public
#include "ClassA.h"

// ready for testing :)
```

Comment: this is ill-formed, and some compilers catch that

Comment: A very bad idea. You have no assurance that this will work. For one thing the layout might change.